# how Express server can talk to React Js Component

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having express Server which needs to communicate with the React Component by passing a variable to the React JS Component.

Express server code:

```
app.all('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.user['cn'];
    var emailaddress = req.user['emailaddress'];
    res.sendFile(BUILD+"/index.html");
});
```

Here ensureAuthenticated is the Single Sign-On function which authenticates the user before rendering the Page. I need to pass the name and emailaddress variables of the logged User to a React Component. How can I achieve this?

Thanks and Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

you can't send a user object with `sendFile` but ideally what you can do is to send only the file as you did:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(BUILD+"/index.html");
});
```

and then on the react side  you can create an action creator to fetch the current user in the main component you have for example:

```
componentWillMount() {
   this.props.fetchUser();
}
```

the fetchUser action creator will be something like so:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {     
    const res = await axios.get('/api/current_user');  
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data }); 
 };
```

and in your reducer you will have :

```
export default function(state = null, action) { 
 switch (action.type) {                             
  case FETCH_USER:
     return action.payload || false;        
  default:
    return state;
 }   
}
```

and then you can setup a route handler in the express side for handling the react action :

```
app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {       
   res.send(req.user);                            
});
```

then in your react side you can save the user object in the localStorage

and then any route on the backend you want to make sure the user must be authenticated you can add your middleware `ensureAuthenticated` to the route handlers.

in my answer i assumed you're using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)